# What makes the 'getCharNumber' method case-insensitive while it only every checks for lowercase (by author of CtCI)

Tags: java, case-insensitive

```java
public class Common {

    public static int getCharNumber(Character c) {
        int a = Character.getNumericValue('a');
        int z = Character.getNumericValue('z');
        
        int val = Character.getNumericValue(c);
        if (a <= val && val <= z) {
            return val - a;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    
    public static int[] buildCharFrequencyTable(String phrase) {
        int[] table = new int[Character.getNumericValue('z') - Character.getNumericValue('a') + 1];
        for (char c : phrase.toCharArray()) {
            int x = getCharNumber(c);
            if (x != -1) {
                table[x]++;
            }
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

Above algorithm was used for testing whether a string is a permuation of a palindrome and was authored by CtCI (Cracking the Coding Interview).

***My question***: Why is the `getCharNumber` method case-insensitive?

I thought it should to be case-sensitive as it only checks for lowercase characters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, I suggest before asking _Why is X_ type of questions [be to sure to have (re)searched](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5698098) for the answer youself (and also include that fact in your question description). Also take care to include the relevant tags; in particular the tag for your programming language `java`.

Comment: _As a hint_ check the API documentation for the used classes and methods; i.e. [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html), in particular [getNumericValue(char)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Why is the getCharNumber case-insensitive?*

The `getCharNumber` method uses Java's `Character#getNumericValue(char)` method for which its [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) states in particular:

> The letters A-Z in their uppercase ('\u0041' through '\u005A'), lowercase ('\u0061' through '\u007A'), and full width variant ('\uFF21' through '\uFF3A' and '\uFF41' through '\uFF5A') forms have numeric values from 10 through 35. This is independent of the Unicode specification, which does not assign numeric values to these char values.

Meaning that for example for character `A` and `a` this API method returns *the same value*, i.e. `10`, and thus there's no case-sensitivity.

---

For reference, see also

- [Character.getNumericValue(..) in Java returns same number for upper and lower case characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31888001/5698098)
- [What is the reverse of Character.getNumericValue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24101052/5698098)
- [Java Character literals value with getNumericValue()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13717898/5698098)
- [Character.getNumericValue() issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2148096/5698098)
- [Character.getNumericvalue in char Frequency table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44711311/5698098)

Comment: So, basically, the "numeric value" is the value the character would represent when used in a base-16, base-32 or base-whatever number representation? Interesting. I'd have expected it to return the ASCII value.